# Why I can't save data in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Why I can't save data in PhpStorm?

Occurred:

> "Unable to save settings : Failed to save settings . Please restart PhpStorm".

Comment: It may help: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000163604-phpstorm-2018-1-log-error-Unable-to-save-settings-Failed-to-save-settings-Please-restart-PhpStorm-

Comment: can be caused by a dozen of reasons - file locking, broken configurations, third-party plugins,... Please provide your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

Comment: If anyone is trying to run WSL2 and then edit via the Windows host in Phpstorm and getting the same error, I found chaning the nginx user from www-data to your linux user when you terminal into wsl did the trick. I tried addiing the native user to the www-data group and didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 2):

It is noteworthy that PHPStorm log files are saved to the .idea folder which may be hidden by default and in my case running:

```
chmod -R 755 *
```

did not apply the requested permissions to the hidden folders within my current directory. I was only able to resolve the issue by running chmod to the .idea folder:

```
chmod -R 755 .idea
```

Hope this is helpful to someone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved it by the following:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 *path where is your web server files located, for me, it's /var/www*
```

The error occurs because the PHPStorm didn't have access to creating log files in /var/www directory
Hope it helps someone too

Comment: Why should phpStorm log to the Webserver?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was found at phpStorm:

> The issue was the local idea directory in the project. I deleted this,
> and it fixed the issue. However, all my project settings are gone too,
> so not an ideal solution.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000163604-phpstorm-2018-1-log-error-Unable-to-save-settings-Failed-to-save-settings-Please-restart-PhpStorm-

Answer (score 0):

### Drive space issues!?

I had similar issues and then I realized my drive was full.
So check for free disk space on your repository source drive (where you store your local VSC Git clone).